# Cannot use [] for reading when including

Tags: php

I have this PHP file:

```
<?php

namespace FrameWork\Controller;

abstract class ControllerBase
{

    protected $action;
    protected $vars;

    public function __construct($action, $vars = NULL)
    {
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->vars = $vars;

        $this->populateVars();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        ****BETWEEN HERE****
        $r = new \ReflectionMethod($this, $this->action);
        $params = $r->getParameters();

        $funcParams[];

        foreach($params as $param)
        {
            $paramName = $param->getName();
            $funcParams[$paramName] = $this->vars[$paramName];
        }
        ****AND HERE****

        call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->action), $funcParams);
    }

    private function PopulateVars()
    {
        foreach($_GET as $key => $getVar)
        {
            $this->vars[$key] = $getVar;
        }

        foreach($_POST as $key => $postVar)
        {
            $this->vars[$key] = $postVar;
        }
    }
}
```

It is `include`ed in another file, and for some reason I am getting an exception thrown on the `include`.

`Cannot use [] for reading`

When I remove everything between `****BETWEEN HERE****` and `****AND HERE****`, it works (or at least doesn't throw the same exception).

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What is ```$funcParams[];```?

Comment: I think it needs to be `$funcParams = [];`, since it's used as an array that things are added to a few lines later.

Comment: @rickdenhaan maybe, but it's worth to mention that in PHP there's no need to declare variable before blocks such as loops, ifs etc. It will be recognized outside block without any problems.

Comment: @Wolen True, but in this case it looks like a simple typo where the `=` was forgotten.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I know and probably it's true, just saying as something additional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

```
$funcParams[];
```

with

```
$funcParams = array();
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: That did it. Is this new in PHP? I could swear I used to declare arrays like that. (I know I don't *have* to, but it's habits from C#)